# Missed calls on lock screen iPhone 11 Pro

Tags: notifications

I don't mind seeing the missed call notification, but the instant redial feature results in too many unwanted calls.

Like returning spam and political calls I didn't want in the first place. I have "Return missed calls" turned off in settings but some other factor is overriding it.

Yes, I'd like to see what missed call the notification is referring to, but I'll forgo that luxury if it means I instantly return the call.

Comment: Don't you have to go through the 2nd step of unlocking the phone to perform any action on the notification? I miss a call, I lift the phone. It tells me who called.. only then do I either tap or swipe to perform any action.

Answer (score 0):

Notification bodies are protected on the lock screen by default. You don't need to tap the notification to see what the message in the notification is; in fact, that causes the redial.

When you get a notification that just says ‘Notification’, look at your device to unlock it. If your device isn't looking for your face, slightly slide up from the bottom of the device. When the device is unlocked, the notification text will be revealed.

No need to swipe all the way up to the home screen and don't tap the notification.

Comment: I try not to tap the notification -- though it would be nice if I could to see what it's about -- but the screen gets touched. Sue me. What I want is to turn off "tap to redial." What sense does it make to "tap to redial" when you don't even know who you're redialing TO?